# How to fetch message from SQL Server Queue in Spring Data JPA

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using the SQL Server database which contains queue i.e. queueXXX.

I want to run the following code from Spring data JPA and return the list of message from the queue.

```
 declare @result table(
    [message_body] varbinary(MAX)
    , [message_type_name] nvarchar(256)
    , [validation] nchar(2)
    , [message_enqueue_time] datetime
    , [conversation_handle] uniqueidentifier
);

waitfor (
    receive top (1) [message_body], [message_type_name], [validation], [message_enqueue_time], [conversation_handle]
    from queueXXX
    into @result
), timeout 10000;

declare @c uniqueidentifier = (select top 1 [conversation_handle] from @result);

-- End the conversation so sending a message back to the sender who will close 
-- their side of the conversation.
--
if @c is not null
    end conversation @c;

-- Only return the first row as we will not have any other messages
select top 1 [message_body], LTRIM(RTRIM([message_type_name])) as [message_type_name], LTRIM(RTRIM([validation])) as [validation], [message_enqueue_time], [conversation_handle] from @result;
```

I have tried following approach to get this work. but it doesn't work.

```
@Repository
public class QueueReaderDao {
    @PersistenceContext 
    EntityManager entityManager;

public void readQueue(){
    
    Query q =entityManager.createNamedQuery("declare @result table( " + 
        "   [message_body] varbinary(MAX) " + 
        "   , [message_type_name] nvarchar(256) " + 
        "   , [validation] nchar(2) " + 
        "   , [message_enqueue_time] datetime " + 
        "   , [conversation_handle] uniqueidentifier " + 
        "); " + 
        " " + 
        "waitfor ( " + 
        "   receive top (1) [message_body], [message_type_name], [validation], [message_enqueue_time], [conversation_handle] " + 
        "   from queueXXX " + 
        "   into @result " + 
        "), timeout 10000; " + 
        " " + 
        "declare @c uniqueidentifier = (select top 1 [conversation_handle] from @result); " + 
        " " + 
        "-- End the conversation so sending a message back to the sender who will close  " + 
        "-- their side of the conversation. " + 
        "-- " + 
        "if @c is not null " + 
        "   end conversation @c; " + 
        " " + 
        "-- Only return the first row as we will not have any other messages " + 
        "select top 1 [message_body], LTRIM(RTRIM([message_type_name])) as [message_type_name], LTRIM(RTRIM([validation])) as [validation], [message_enqueue_time], [conversation_handle] from @result;");
    
    q.getResultList();
    
    System.out.println("query works");
}
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of the batch.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Thanks for the input. Still, it failed to work. it shows error as "InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No query defined for that name"